# Why does my OpenProcess(..) call always return 0?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to open the process "winlogon.exe" from a windows Service. To do so I use the `OpenProcess` method. Unfortunately this always fails (return a null pointer). And it doesn't set the error flag. (Accessed with `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`).

I use this definition of Open Process :

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern UIntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);
```

I tried different Access levels and it doesnt' change anything.

And I Use it this way :

```cs
int winlogonPid=0;
//int MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 1 << 25;
IntPtr hPToken = new IntPtr(0);

// obtain the process id of the winlogon process that 
// is running within the currently active session
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winlogon");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
                if (GetUsernameBySessionId(p.SessionId, true) == "foo\bar")
                {
                    winlogonPid = p.Id;
                }
                WriteToFile("Service found the process with session name: " + GetUsernameBySessionId(p.SessionId,true));

}

WriteToFile("FirstError:" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

// obtain a handle to the winlogon process
uint READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000; //https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
UIntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(READ_CONTROL, false, (uint)winlogonPid);
WriteToFile("Open Process Handle : " + hProcess.ToUInt64());
WriteToFile("SecondError:" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

The output log is as follow :

```cs
Service has started at 22/07/2019 15:47:47
Service found the process with session name: foo\bar
FirstError:183
Open Process Handle : 0
SecondError:183
Service has stopped at 22/07/2019 15:47:47
```

*Using this signature https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.openprocess gives me the same result.*

Comment: I don't like your 0x400 literal. Should be a symbolic constant. Too hard to read otherwise.

Comment: Yes you're right, I corrected it. Yet I could do it better by creating the enum type.

Comment: This is very likely a security feature of Windows.

Comment: Considering that this is part of the critical security infrastructure of Windows, I'd be surprised if you were allowed to tinker with it. Why exactly are you trying to start this process? Perhaps there's a different way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to spawn a process on a user session from a windows service. Following this :  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite . I'm aware that the reason I have to bypass it, is that this is not a good practice starting windows vista. I want to inform the user after printing (virtual printer) a doc that he can see it at a given URL. And I need it to be a Windows Service process.

Comment: I think you need to run your service in session 0. Also please move ```WriteToFile("Service found the process with session name: " + GetUsernameBySessionId(p.SessionId,true));
``` line inside the conditional block.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just had a problem with OpenProcess returning 0, and I solved it by running Visual Studio in Admin-Mode